# No Monobehavior Scripts in this file -- no files are being read

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner at C# and Unity. All my C# Scripts in Unity are showing the issue - "No Monobehavior Scripts in this file, or their names do not match the file name." 
My file and class name is exactly the same and I think that the issue arises from the Assembly information in the picture below but I am unsure of how to resolve it. Currently using Visual Studio to edit the code.

Already insured that file and class name are same. Removed and reinstalled the files, and also removed my antivirus Mcafee since I read that it may cause interference with unity.

[image: Click here to see the image of issue]

[image: Click here to see compiler error messages]

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any compiler errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting multiple errors

Comment: Have edited post to show compiler errors

Comment: Well as we can now see there are lots of  compiler errors ... until these are fixed your class script isn't even (re)compiled so Unity doesn't know it yet ... First fix all compiler errors. They seem to be particularly related to the "inline out" declaration within the `TextMeshPro` package. Did you change the Unity Version or .Net version shortly? (You'll need c# 7 / .Net4.6) for this

Comment: My current Unity version is 2019.1.2f1. I'm unsure of how to check my .Net version/ I am unsure of how to fix that compiler issue

Answer (score 0):

your scripts are not compiled and cannot be found because there are errors in them. 
The errors are about the out parameter. Try updating the scripting runtime:

Go to **Edit>Project** **Settings>Player**, then select **Other Settings** tab and in **Configuration** block try switching **Scripting Runtime** Version to **.NET 4.x Equivalent**.